# Avoid dummy text on an AJAX search (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code for an AJAX-based search in the event "the user stops writing". Now I want to detect when the user is writing  a fast succesion of characters with no sense, something like type 'edkpakdpakffnhnsc' dummy string.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var inputTimer;
        var lol = $('input#lol');
        var hola = $('#hola');

        hola.hide();

        $('#lol').keyup( function(){


            if(lol.val().length >= 3){

                clearTimeout(inputTimer);
                inputTimer = setTimeout(ajaxFunction, 500);

                function ajaxFunction(){
                    hola.show();
                }

            } else {
                hola.hide();
            }
            });

    });
```

How I have to approach this problem???

Thanks

Comment: Not sure you can do that without a dictionary to lookup (very slow). Any attempt to guage only by the speed of typing won't be fair on those who are fast typers.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the type of input (name, address, first line of a poem) and its expected language (perhaps Spanish?), it would be impossible to trap "illegal" chars one-by-one while a word is being typed without knowing all possible 'legal' words, which would require quite a lot of memory which in most use cases would be unacceptable. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I agree with Gats, and i understand Rob, but i still need to do something like that :P. How can i do it based on "type speed"?

Comment: You'd need to create a tree data structure to represent all possible words with one node for each character and I suspect such a tree--assuming only 10,000 words of an average of six characters--would contain something just shy of 60,000 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea for many reasons

1. **Power:** It would take a huge amount of processing and memory usage to detect if a certain string is probably garbage. I say "probably" because you cannot account for every bit of linguistic text; your code will have to decide at the end of the day if it'll accept it or not, and in cases it'll get it wrong.
2. **Localizations:** A vast amount of knowledge will be required to cater for all localizations, languages, etc. What about non-dictionary words but are a valid search terms across your site.
3. **Fast typers:** Those who are fast typers will be punished. I'm screwed.
4. **Performance:** Your ironically lowering performance, not increasing it
5. **Innocent users being hurt:** By doing this, your hurting users who aren't exploiting your system. If a malicious user wants to enter random garbage; punish just that user.

#### A better idea for performance

I would advise to focus on only allowing a certain number of searches per minute or so. This will mean a malicious user can't constantly be hitting your site with search queries which potentially take a lot of resources to generate. Make sure the threshold is reasonable, i.e. max 8 searches per minute.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming you already have a tree of legal words structured as:

```
var wordtree={
  'a': {
    'isWord': true,                   // 'a' is a word
    '_': {
      'r': {
        'isWord': false,              // 'ar' is not a word
        '_': {
          'e': {
            'isWord': true            // 'are' is a word
          },
          't': {
            'isWord': true            // 'art' is a word
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  'b': {
    'isWord': false,                  // 'b' is not a word
      ...
    }
  }
};
```

you can check the validity of words as they are typed with:

```
function check(str) {
  var wordtree={ ... }, // as described above
      words=str.split(/\s+|[[:punct:]]+/);

  for(var i=0,len=words.length;i<len;i++) { // for each word in str
    var start=wordtree, word=words[i];

    for(var j=0,jlen=word.length,last=jlen-1;j<jlen;j++) { // for each char in word
      var ch=word.charAt(j), 
          current=start[ch], 
          type=current ? typeof current : undefined;

      if( !current || 
          (j < last && type !== 'object') || 
          (j===last && !current['isWord']) 
      ) {
        console.log('word('+word+') fails');
        return false;
      }
      start=current['_'];
    }
    console.log('word('+word+') succeeds');
  }

  return true;
}
```

This should perform well in realtime, though for any conceivable language, wordtree will be enormous.